# Load latest jQuery library using PHP

Tags: jquery

I wonder if there is method or posibility to load latest jQuery library to with PHP.

Let's say at the moment I have:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I would like to achiev something like:

```
<script src="$latest-jquery-url" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Where `$latest-jquery-url` would be updated on page load.

And most important, is that a wise thing to do? Any compatibility issue could occur or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to keep up with jQuery latest version:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

This will always have the latest jQuery that Google serves without you changing the version number, however **this *can* break** your web application without notice when outdated functions are used.

Comment: **Note:** this breaks the main reason for using Google AJAX Libraries in the first place: the file will no longer be cached and it will force the client to download it again, even if they were just at a site using the same version of jQuery. It is *not* recommended to do this.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the jQuery CDN at Media Temple](http://code.jquery.com/), [this link](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js) is for the most recent stable minified version.  No PHP code or server-side processing required.

Comment: Exactly I was looking for, couldn't really find an answer to it .S

Comment: Has jQuery authorized using this URL in your own apps, though? After all, they're paying for the bandwidth. You should make sure they're okay with you simply hotlinking it.

Answer (score 3):

There certainly is! But why would you wan't to do this?

You could just do:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To get the latest version, but that has some caching issues, and I would recommend just sticking with one version instead.

On the serverside all you have to do is set up a cron job to wget the file everyday, and either use a querystring that is dynamic with a timestamp or something, or just turn of caching of js files all together.

Answer (score 1):

They deprecate and remove functions sometimes. There's almost no need for this.

However, if you really need to, you can continuously check high versions until one doesn't exist, then use the previous one. First, find the highest main version number (the first part) by checking for 2.1.1, then 3.1.1, then 4.1.1... Right now you know 2.1.1 will be missing, so then start on the second number.. 1.1.1, 1.2.1, 1.3.1, 1.4.1.. You'll find that 1.7.1 is the latest, then start on the third number.. 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, you'll find that 1.7.1 is the latest, so include that one.

There would be quite a bit of delay doing all those lookups, but it should be fairly short.

Alternatively, store 1.7.1 in your DB, and on page load check for the next newest version and update the DB with it. If your DB contains 2.7.1, check for 2.7.2, 2.8.1, and 3.1.1, updating the DB as necessary.

Comment: This is a good way to FIND the version number, just including the latest version by default is answered in those other questions but finding the version number can be harder as it may change location in the .js

Comment: Actually this sounds like a stupid idea! All you have to do is request the newest version from the Google API, and they will actually send you the newest version, imagine! If you really wanted to know what the version number of that "newest jQuery" was, all you had to do was type `$().jquery;` and it would output the version number nice and and neat in a string for you!

Comment: Thats in JS though, not PHP. The only way to truly do it server-side is either download the latest JS and find the version number, or guess-and-check until you find it.

Comment: Well, no! All you need to do is use the Google adress in the answers above in cURL and it will always give you the source for the newest version, no guessing needed. The version number is ALWAYS in the first comment in the JQ file, so it's not that hard to extract it with a simple preg_match or something similar, but why would you need it if you already knew it was the newest version ? And why on earth would you store the entire jQuery library in a DB, and then insert the entire source in a php file on every pageload, with no caching, wouldn't it be better to atleast save it in a JS file ?